# Is it okay to remove earlier versions of snaps?

Tags: snap

Almost all of snaps on my system which have duplicates that differ only in version number.

1. Do the latest snaps depend on the earlier snaps, or is it okay to delete the earlier snaps?
2. If it's okay to delete the earlier snaps, is there a command that will take care of this like `apt autoclean` and `apt autoremove`?

Here's an example of the duplication. Some of the snaps appear to differ by major-version number; others appear to differ only by minor-version number.

```
wine-platform-3-stable_10.snap
wine-platform-3-stable_11.snap
wine-platform-5-stable_13.snap
wine-platform-5-stable_16.snap
```

Comment: Yes it is okay. Just be a little bit careful when you remove things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the maximum number of snap revisions stored for each package by setting the `refresh.retain` option. The `refresh.retain` option can only be an integer between 2 and 20 and has a default value of 3. <sup>[source](https://superuser.com/a/1361201/)</sup>

It's OK to remove earlier versions of snap packages down to the minimum number of saved snap revisions of 2. The following command changes the number of saved snap revisions from the default value of 3 to 2.

```
sudo snap set system refresh.retain=2
```

Comment: Thanks! When does snapd remove the old snaps? Is there an action I can take to trigger the cleanup?

Comment: snapd removes old snap revisions automatically triggered by the installation of an updated snap version. You can install any updates to snap packages that are available manually from the terminal by running `sudo snap refresh`